# Subgrid slides into overflow on window resize on Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, css-grid

For several elements I have data arranged like a table with `grid` and `subgrid`. However, for the one element which spans the full width of its parent, all of the `subgrid` elements will slide away when I resize the window
[image: subgrid sliding out from parent grid]
Here I have only one `subgrid` highlighted, but they all slide out together.

It is also much more jittery upon resizing in Firefox, whereas when I tested it in Chrome it is very smooth and without any issues. I thought it was related to how I have text truncated inside the subgrid, but after testing that wasn't the issue. I tried various configurations of the subgrid, but nothing seemed to work.
The Less CSS looks something like this:

```
.pen-grid > li {
  grid-template-columns: subgrid;
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: -1;
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
}
.pen-grid {
  display: grid;
  width: fit-content;
  justify-content: center;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: @gap;
  row-gap: @gap-small;
}
.events {
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr repeat(2, max-content);
  span:nth-of-type(2) {
    max-width: 100%
  }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<ol class="events pen-grid">
    <li>
        <span>TableHeader1</span>
        <span></span>
        <span>TableHeader2</span>
        <span></span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="summarize">Date</span>
        <span class="summarize">Name</span>
        <span>{{this.system.glory}}</span>
        <span>
            <a class="item-edit" data-item-id="{{this._id}}"><i class="fas fa-pen-to-square"></i></a>
            <a class="item-delete" data-item-id="{{this._id}}"><i class="fas fa-xmark"></i></a>
        </span>
    </li>
</ol>
```

What I would most like is to be able to preserve this element structure, and so I am hoping there is something I could change in the CSS to prevent this issue on Firefox (119.0.1)